# How can you umount `/home`?

Tags: filesystems, mount

When log in Lubuntu, I can't

```
$ sudo umount /home
umount: /home: target is busy.
```

where `/home` itself is a mount point of a filesystem.

How can you umount `/home`?

`/` can't be umounted, because OS is running from it. Can `/home` be easier to be umounted?

Thanks.

Comment: Linux don't allow you to umount a mount point if there's still some living reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can unmount `/home` if it's an independent file system. The `Target is busy` message means that there are either:

1. files under `/home` that are still open
2. directories under `/home` that are the CWD of some process (this could be the shell from which you try to unmount `/home`)
3. a filesystem mounted on a mount point under `/home`

For 1) and 2), the `lsof` command can help, but if you are using a GUI, you have very many files permanently open under `/home/{your id}` so unmounting `/home` is not going to be easy. If you log using a TTY instead of a GUI, you can better control what process are running with your id and what files are open.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it is better to boot into a live Lubuntu so that the `/home` on disk  is not mounted by default?

Comment: Yes, it could make things easier. But why do you want to unnount `/home`?.

Comment: I agree that it’ll be difficult if your logged in (even at the text console) as a user, if your ~ is on /home, but I want to warn you that even if you manage to log in as root, you might encounter a situation where /home is unmountable. If you use systemd and you have any services that have ProtectHome=read-only, it will have a bind mount of home that will prevent /home from being uncounted. It won’t show it in lsof, since it is a kernel syscall.